# How to get image file name in php

Tags: php, image, url

let say i have this folder to store captcha image

```
$directory = "http://localhost/test/wp-content/plugins/test/captcha/";
```

i try alot of codes like opendir, glob() etc trying together my image file name from the directory above but fail.

image file name is captcha.jpeg.

i have no choice but to use static url as shown below. but my captcha will be generating images with random (name).jpeg that is why i need a dynamic way to get image file whereby *.jpeg

```
$directory="http://localhost/test/wpcontent/plugins/test/captcha/captcha.jpeg";
```

i wants to get the whole image url return as json. Please anyone have resource to help me thanks.

```
return array("image url" => $image_url);
```

Comment: Why not save your image name in session/cookie upon creation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try it?

```
$path_parts = pathinfo('http://localhost/test/wpcontent/plugins/test/captcha/captcha.jpeg');

$returnArray = ['image url' => $path_parts['basename']];

return json_encode($returnArray);
```

It return:

```
{
    "image_url" : "captcha.jpeg"
}
```

[Pathinfo() PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pathinfo.php)